# How to save accented characters into a new custom field on Contact

Tags: xml

When international customers (Spanish/French/etc) are giving their contact names with accent formats. So we have a problem with those special accented characters conversion in integration when it is converted to xml format ftp and sending to SAP. So what we are planning is, we can convert their name into english without accent and send this value through integration.

Comment: Are you specifying the encoding in your XML file? (like <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>)